# Printing the value of "p+p[3]-p[1]"

Tags: c, string, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char c[]="HELLO2014";
    char *p;
    printf("%s\n",p+p[3]-p[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code in C outputs 14 in Answer .Please Explain this How?

Comment: This seems like you are making things more difficult than they need to be... What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This code causes undefined behaviour because `p+p[3]` is outside the bounds of `c` .

Answer (score 3):

This is a trick.

First your snippet is missing a statement, you should add `char *p = c`; or use directly `c` in the `printf`.

```
p[3]-p[1]
```

These are chars L and E corresponding to 76 and 69 in ASCII codes.

So your `printf` becomes

```
printf("%s\n",p + 7 );
```

which shifts the char array by 7 thus `14`